# Include form name in serialize()

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

Is there a way to include the form name in serialize() function of JQuery?

Right now in $_POST is like:

```
$_POST = ['key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2'];
```

And I would like it to be:

```
$_POST = [ 'formName'=>[ 'key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2'] ];
```

I can't find any way for JQuery to include the form's name.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way around this, would be adding a <input type="hidden"> containing the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by modifying your form like this:

```
   <input name="formName[key1]" />
   <input name="formName[key2]" />
```

And so on...
PHP understands such names and turns them into multidimensional arrays inside `$_POST`